# Where to get dashboard screws for Volvo XC90?

Tags: volvo, dashboard, screw

The dashboard of a 2006 Volvo XC90 has a roughly ring shaped plastic part that goes on top of the transparent dash cover, and it's held in place by two screws. In this case these screws appear to have somehow gone missing, and the plastic cover slips out easily (which is undesirable when driving).

Where can I get new ones? Are they just a standard screw, or some special screw that only Volvo makes and sells at 100x times the price of a regular screw? What do I even search for?

For clarity, the below photo shows what I mean. I've outlined the plastic "dash cover" in red, and the two screws are circled with purple.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the mentioned photo here. Perhaps you can upload it somewhere else and post the link?

Comment: I forgot to add it, that's all, @EvrenYurtesen

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that you need some plastic fasteners there? There are some photos from another volvo below. Perhaps you can tell if the holes have some threads or not if you look into them with flashlight.
http://www.volvoforums.org.uk/showthread.php?t=184922

I found a parts diagram for your model but those holes are not mentioned :(
http://www.volvopartswebstore.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=236804&ukey_make=865&ukey_model=11985&modelYear=2006&ukey_category=7854

It may be that you need 8mm trim fasteners. (costs $1 for 10 of them :p) They seem to be used in many volvo models including xc90. I may be wrong also, just guessing, so please check the holes :)

See:
https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=volvo+3541113